# How do I access Google Fit user goals in Google Play Services?

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-fit

I'm showing daily user step data and activity time in an Android app using Play Services. I got the API setup ok and this is all working fine, but I'd like to also read the user's **GOALS** (the one's set in the Google Fit profile) for daily steps and activity time so I can show the achieved percentage. How do I achieve this? I cannot find any of the APIs in com.google.android.gms.fitness.* offering this.

Thanks,

Michael

Comment: I have a same question, did you find any solution ?

Comment: Same question over here ! Did you find any answer ?!

Comment: I couldn't find anything either. 
The only thing I found from Google api doc: 
public static final String ACTION_VIEW_GOAL: Broadcast action: the user has requested to view their current fitness goal.

Answer (score 1):

The latest changes in the android play-services (9.8.0) are supposed to
make that possible.

1.Add the Fitness.GOALS_API to the GoogleAPiClient

```
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(CrossoverWatchFaceService.this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks([...])
                .addApi(Fitness.HISTORY_API)
                .addApi(Fitness.GOALS_API)
                .useDefaultAccount()
                .build();
        googleApiClient.connect();
```

2.Retrieve Goal(s)

```
PendingResult<GoalsResult> pendingResult =
        Fitness.GoalsApi.readCurrentGoals(
                googleApiClient,
                new GoalsReadRequest.Builder()
                        .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                         .build());
                pendingResult.setResultCallback(
                new ResultCallbacks<GoalsResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(@NonNull GoalsResult goalsResult) {
                        List<Goal> goals = goalsResult.getGoals();
                        //YOUR CODE HERE
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Status status) {
                        Log.d(TAG, "onFailure: ");
                    }
                });
```

https://developers.google.com/fit/android/using-goals

and

https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/GoalsApi

Answer (score 0):

As of now (9/22/15), it's not possible to get step goal from Google Fit API.

Notes: ACTION_VIEW_GOAL only allows user to view. And I couldn't get it to work either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use sync call, use below code snippet for 2nd part Retrieve Goal:

```
PendingResult<GoalsResult> pendingResult = Fitness.GoalsApi.readCurrentGoals(
            googleApiClient, new GoalsReadRequest.Builder()
                    .addDataType(DataType.TYPE_STEP_COUNT_DELTA)
                    .build());

GoalsResult goalsResult = pendingResult.await();
List<Goal> goals = goalsResult.getGoals();
// assume 1st goal is step count
double stepGoal = goals.get(0).getMetricObjective().getValue();
```